# Why the url in which index.php is prefix with first segment in codeigniter works | Codeigniter | RewriteCond

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working on a CodeIgniter project and today I found a very strange issue.

When I open the URL that is prefixed with `index.php` in the first segment it is still working even though I expect the URL to return a `404 Not Found` page.

For example, the URL of my website is `http://localhost/project` and when I open the URL `http://localhost/project/jobs` it works fine, but when I open `http://localhost/project/index.phpjobs` it also works.

I don't know what is going on over here!

Please note that the URL **doesn't include slash** but is still working and that is not a typo.

Please check in your project and let me know if someone have the same problem because I think this problem may also exist in your current project but not noticed.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^.well-known/ - [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

will be honored only if the previous two conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

have been met.

Now, the trick lies in these conditions which basically say that the rewrite will be performed only if the requested resource (`REQUEST_FILENAME` here) does not exist as either a file or a folder.

Since `index.php` obviously exists the rewrite rule is skipped and the server actually receives the original (non-rewritten) request.

That is the reason why you see the same result for requests that both do and do not contain `/index.php/` as prefix.

The same applies for both sets of rewrite, the one you are using for your admin page and the regular one.

Comment: Hi man, did you notice that my question is about why the first segment prefixed with index.php(no slash between index.php and first segment) is working?